# Ignored build paths in sencha touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

When i try to build my package for production the custom build path i have set up in my app.json is ignored. I got this in my buildPath:

```
"buildPaths": {
        "testing":    "build/testing",
        "production": "build/project/assets/www",
        "package":    "build/project/assets/www",
        "native":     "build/native",
},
```

The thing is when i run this command in my command line:

```
sencha app build production
```

The commandline continues and ends without an error. But when i look into my buildpath, i only see a folder called: production. Why are these buildpaths ignored? I assume that when i set these values that my app will go into the build/project/assets/www folder. What is wrong?

```
Sencha touch version: 2.1.0-rc1
Sencha CMD version: V3.0.0.190
```

Comment: Are you on windows? Have you tried using absolute paths?

Comment: I tried that, but that didn't work. And yes i am on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a sort of workaround. First thing i tried is setting an absolute path, but that didn't helped (Yes i am on windows).

The reason i needed to change the path is: I got an eclipse (android/phonegap) project in that folder. And each time i builded the sencha application the path was incorrect. So i just changed my loadurl in the eclipse project to:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/production/index.html");
    }
```

instead of:

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
```

not really a solution because it still ignores the build path, but it isn't a problem for me anymore.

Answer (score 2):

`buildPaths` in `app.json` are deprecated (and do not work anymore as of Sencha Touch 2.1.0 and Sencha Cmd v3.0.0.250)

You have to configure the paths as shown in `./sencha/app/build-impl.xml`.

That file is imported by the `./build.xml` file, so the changes should be done in this final file, if possible.

I don't know exactly how to set the build path, because what I needed was slightly different.

I wanted the **packaged** files to be copied inside a directory which will then be used by Phonegap.

What I changed to the build-impl.xml file was the `-after-build` declaration, writing a `copy` statement inside, as shown:

```
<target name="-after-build">
    <copy todir="../phonegap_project/www">
        <fileset dir="${workspace.build.dir}/package"/>
    </copy>
</target>
```

eventually, if you need to empty the destination directory beforehand, you can add

```
    <delete dir="../phonegap_project/www"/>
```

just before the `copy` statement.

Then, I build using the `sencha app build package` command.

Reference: [the sencha forum on this same issue](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?248709-Sencha-CMD-3.0.0.230-buildPaths-not-taken-into-account)

Comment: thanks your "copy" code snippet. searched this a long time, but the "build.xml" isn't documented.

Answer (score 1):

Hello guys im using Sencha cmd **v5+**.

For me the following lines under  tag of build.xml at root of project run like a charm.

```html
<target name="-after-build">
  <copy todir="../../gap/NAME_OF_MY_PROJECT_DIRECTORY/www">
    <fileset dir="${workspace.build.dir}/../package"/>
  </copy>
</target>
```

Sorry for my bad english, but im learning.